# Dumbing down Fairy lights

Tags: usb

I purchased a set of these lights:

https://a.co/d/3wixp7R

"66FT 200 LED Fairy String Lights Outdoor/Indoor, Super Bright Fairy Lights with Remote, Waterproof Copper Wire 8 Modes"

With the intent to use them in a child's room, hooked up to a switched outlet in a 'steady on' state

These lights have tons of modes, and no memory. so when they are switched off and back on, they are "off" and need to be turned on via the included ir remote, then cycled through 8 modes to get to regular "solid on"

Can I simply cut off the small  circuit panel usb-a at the end of the lights and replace it with a $1 2-wire 5v usb-a pigtail? I don't know what kind of tolerances are in these types of lights and whether I'd be creating a pretty fire hazard.

Edit: adding pic as requested

[image: USB plug end]

Comment: Post a picture of the "small circuit panel" with the components visible otherwise it is hard to know what it does.

Comment: Generally yes, you can cut off the circuit board and just hook up the LEDs to power. What kind of power is needed I don't know. Looking at the circuit board would be one way to figure that out, so please add a photo. (It could also be figured out by looking at how all the LEDs are wired, but it's probably easier to look at the one circuit board). There's not too many different ways for the maker to wire dumb fairy lights. I guess all the lights are connected together so they all flash on/off at the same time - or maybe 2 different groups.

Comment: A photo of both sides of the board may  be useful. Well lit, well focused, fill much of frame... All that stuff :-) || Probably straight connection OK but photos may help

Comment: The leds support "chasing" and other modes so they might be more complicated than a simple string.

Comment: I did my best to capture the circuit board, thanks all for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's generally possible. However, you'll usually find that the LEDs are in two anti-parallel groups, so with DC, only half will be on at a time. If you need them all on, you will need AC. However, using a mains transformer to light them will result in a very low flicker frequency, probably unacceptable  for room lighting.

You'll need to determine what current the LEDs need, and what the minimum voltage of the string is. Start by aiming at 10 mA. Use a variable power supply, with a series resistor, and a meter to monitor your current, and gradually increase the supply until they glow. My set needed 17 V before it started conducting significantly.

The higher the current you choose, the brighter they will be, but the less time they will last. Feel the temperature of the 'on' LEDs after 10 minutes, they should feel no hotter than barely warm to the touch.

Once you've found the drive requirements, you could build an AC source to drive both polarities. Use a frequency of at least 1 kHz to avoid visible flicker. A class D mono audio amplifier with bridge outputs, or a motor full bridge driver might be suitable modules for doing this if you don't want to design at component level, they are available on your favourite eCommerce site for a few dollars.

Comment: Appreciate your info.  Fyi, added pics of the controller to the OP.